# Showing attributes from a different rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, model-associations

I know this is probably an extremely basic level question, but I'm new to rails and can't seem to locate a clear answer in the Ruby Guides on my own; it's likely that I just don't know the term for this and can't figure it out.

I've got two models, documents and companies (companies is a table built by devise).  Companies `has_many :documents` and documents `belongs_to :companies`.  On my form there is a place for the company's name, address, etc., and I would like to populate the associated company on both on the `_form.html.erb` and the `show.html.erb` so that it's not necessary to input this information every time you fill out a form.  It's not absolutely necessary that the information be present on the `_form.html.erb`, but it would be nice to go ahead and present this information so as to not confuse the user.

When I try calling `@companies.company_name` in my documents show view, I hit a nil class error.  I've tried adding `@companies = companies.all` to my controller, but that doesn't work either.  Like I said, I'm sure this is a simple problem, but I don't have much hair left and would like to preserve it for another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a different method that seems to be working well at the moment.  Instead of adding `@company = Company.find (params[:id])`, I was able to call `@document.company.company_name` within the show action.  I'll forgo to the new and edit for the moment since show was all that mattered.